# Add a widget at the end of wrapping text in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to imitate the behavior of many social media platforms that display the category of the post right beside the title like this example from reddit:

[image]

How would I replicate this effect in Flutter? I can't use a row since it would just split at some point and can't accommodate for wrapping text. Is there a way to add a widget at then end of any line on a text widget in Flutter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `RichText` like this:

```
RichText(
    text: TextSpan(children: [
      TextSpan(
        text:
            'sadasd as dasdasdasds as asdsa asdasd as d as dasd das das asdasd as dsa?',
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
      ),
      WidgetSpan(
          child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12),
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2, horizontal: 8),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.red,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
        child: Text(
          '!uestion',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
      )),
    ]),
  )
```

[image]

Comment: I just wanted to comment that, `Text.rich` is can do text spans too, also you can do something like this in Dart: `'abc' * 10`, to repeat the string 10 times. Useful for testing :D